# How to use 2 differents version of Python using CMake

Tags: python, cmake, clion

Context:

I'm building a CMake project. This CMake project is running inside a docker container using the CLion remote development in order to develop my code directly in the docker. Therefore all headers and lib are inside the docker.

Now, because my project is splitted into several parts I have a "main" CMakelists.txt which is calling the ones below, like that:

--- CMakelists.txt

------- Project_part1
-------------CMakelists.txt

------- Project_part2
-------------CMakelists.txt

------- Project_part3
-------------CMakelists.txt

*Note: Individually, building each of them works fine.*

Thing is, the Project_part3 **requires** Python2 as interpretor. But the one above (part1, part2) **requires** Python3.

When including only Project_part1 & Project_part2 it build normally on CLion.
When including only Project_part3 it build normally on CLion.

To define which Python version will be used during the build some environment are used and set:

```
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION
PYTHON_EXECUTABLE
```

Part_1 and Part_2 needs ROS_PYTHON_VERSION = 3 and PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/python3
Part_2 needs ROS_PYTHON_VERSION = 2 and PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/python2

But what happened is the first one that get include/build seems to **force** the one after to use the version of Python it used.

What I did try was (pseudo cmake code):

set_env_var_for_part1_part2

include_part1_part2
-> Building on CLion correctly.

set_env_var_for_3

set_env_var_for_part1_part2

include_part1_part2
-> Building on CLion correctly.

set_env_var_for_part1_part2

set_env_var_for_3

include_part1_part2
-> Building on CLion correctly.

### -> No Error

set_env_var_for_3

include_part3
-> Building on CLion correctly.

set_env_var_for_3

set_env_var_for_part1_part2

include_part3
-> Building on CLion correctly.

set_env_var_for_part1_part2

set_env_var_for_3

include_part3
-> Building on CLion correctly.

### -> No Error

set_env_var_for_3

include_part3

set_env_var_for_part1_part2

include_part1_part2
-> ERROR Building on CLion on part1_part2.

set_env_var_for_part1_part2

include_part1_part2

set_env_var_for_3

include_part3
-> ERROR Building on CLion on part3.

... It's just errors whatever I do.

From the errors. Take my words for granted, it is because they respectively don't find some of the package they need to build and it is **because** they are using the wrong version of python. Part1 and Part2 need Python3 and Part3 need Python2.

There is no environment variable set in CLion IDE

Conclusion, setting environment variables doesn't seems to change much. So I went in CMakeCache.txt and found that PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python which could explain that since it's set here and have been found once it might not need to be updated another time. Cleaning cache, removing cmake-build-debug hasn't change anything either.

I'm stuck. I need a way to make all of those programs build using different versions of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, so, indeed the CMakeCache.txt was forcing the path of python to be the first used one. I was trying to change the environment variable but I guess after an env variable has been seen it goes to the CMakeCache.txt and get used instead of actually getting the environment variable.

So instead of changing the Python as I was doing: `set( ENV{PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} /usr/bin/python3)` the good way to go is changing directly the variable in CMake:

```
set( PYTHON_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/python3 )
```